# tableview cell selection in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am getting tableview cell as not selected when i scroll the tableview either in up and down direction. How should i use following method in code?

```
[tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition];
```

Comment: Are u trying this message inside -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ??? Put some code..!

Answer (score 1):

How should i use following method in code?

```
[tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition];
```

*Example*: Add a new cell on the tableview and scroll the table up to added cell added:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.yourDataSource count]-1 inSection:0],nil];
[self.myTableView beginUpdates];
[self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.myTableView endUpdates];
[self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPaths atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```